# How to create a script that users can specify an email and send a user a pre-defined email?

Tags: php, html, email, forms, send

So, basically, I'm creating a page where a user can visit, and enter in the following information: 
1. Their First Name
2. Their Email
3. Recipient's Email

They then can send a pre-defined email, saying something like the following...

"Hello, {Recipient's email}. {First name} ({Email}) has just sent you a slurp! You can ignore this message, or slurp them back.
[Slurp Them Back]   [Slurp Someone Else]   [What's A Slurp?]"


The whole part about the Slurp is something that doesn't really matter, it's just the text from the pre-defined email. The text in {...} is taken from the fields on the page, and the text in [...] are just links. 
 
Does anyone have any idea on how to do this? Even if you can't customize the email, and it would just be without the information from the site, help would be appreciated. Thanks.!


Here's an example of what I'm going for...
[Example Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kIkEI.png)

Comment: You're using the word "email" to mean two different things in your question (an e-mail address and an e-mail message), which makes it more confusing than it should be (especially the headline).

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to do using the php mail function. You can take input for everything you specified, then use the example [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php). They show it in a basic and more advanced form.

Answer (score 0):

Sending an email by itself can be done by using the `mail()` command

```
mail('to.address@host.com', 'subject', 'message', 'From: from.address@host.com');
```

The whole code would look something like this:

HTML:

```
<form action="slurping.php" method="post">
    Your name: <input type="text" name="name" /><br />
    Your email: <input type="text" name="email" /><br />
    Recipient: <input type="text" name="recipient" /><br />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

PHP (slurp.php):

```
// order of parameters is: to, subject, message body, additional headers
mail(
    $_POST['recipient'], 
    'You just got slurped', 
    'You\'ve been slurped by '.$_POST['name'].'. Slurp him/her back by visiting http://slurp.com/',
    "From: {$_POST['email']}\r\n"
);
```

This will send out an email like it's coming from the senders email address to the recipient.

There's a lot missing there, though. What you normally want to include is:

- Validation of input on the client side (javascript)
- Validation of input on the serverside
- Clear out and handle right encodings etc

If you want to do it properly however, so that a greater percentage of your users actually *receive* the email, you should use a 3rd party library to send out emails. I recommend [PHP Mailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/) or [Swift Mailer](http://swiftmailer.org/).

Those libraries provide an easy mechanism for you to include HTML in your emails, attachments, allow for easily connecting to SMTP servers and handle all escaping and encoding issues for you.

On top of that they encapsulate everything within an Object oriented approach, so if that's your cup of tea, you'll be happy. Se their websites for more info.

It's pretty funny, I wrote a blog post about the very issue of email deliverability (getting through spam filters) etc: http://arnorhs.com/2011/02/21/delivering-email-with-php/ - It might be helpful to you.

Cheers

Comment: Hmm, no, not the complete code, though if you do have it, a link would be greatly appreciated. I considered using the mail command, but isn't that only go to an address specified in the page itself? My goal is to get a page visitor to be able to enter an email a text field, and send a pre-defined email to the address they specified.

Comment: Ok, I'll append an (almost) complete example on how to do it to the answer

Comment: Ok, thanks. Will look into the PHP Mailer and Swift Mailer. Also, thanks to everyone else for the quick and helpful answers.

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly, the first chapter of Head First PHP describes almost exactly this scenario (except that the recipient is fixed).  If you want to learn more about PHP you can look into the book; otherwise, their code is online at http://www.headfirstlabs.com/books/hfphp/ (actual code link: http://www.headfirstlabs.com/books/hfphp/code/HeadFirstPHPMySQL_code_ch01.zip)

Answer (score 0):

On submit you can send a predefine email in php

following is the code sample

assumed that you will have a html page and following is the sample html code

Send Slurp

Enter Your Name:  
    Enter Your Email: 
    Enter Recipient's Email:

following is the php code in "="send_email.php"

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{
    $your_name = $_POST['your_name'];
    $your_email = $_POST['your_email']; 
    $recipients_email= $_POST['recipient_email']; 

    $email_subject = 'My Slurp'; 
    $email_body = "Hello, $recipients_email. $your_name ($your_email) has just sent you a slurp! You can ignore this message, or slurp them back.
    [Slurp Them Back] [Slurp Someone Else] [What's A Slurp?]";

    echo $email_body;
    // Send Email
    mail($recipients_email, $email_subject, $email_body);

}
?>
```